# Where to call google API to load charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I am putting the below code inside the `head` tag of my webpage:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(loadAllCharts());
</script>
```

However I am getting this error:

> 37:46 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Where should I place the code in order to generate charts?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script> //add this too

Comment: Add the explicit google js file before body tag closed ie.                       <script type="text/javascript" src="FileLink"></script>                         <script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(loadAllCharts());
</script>                                                                                        </body>

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`?

https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/